# Java Random.nextInt(int) return the same value when set different seeds

Tags: java, random, seed

I wrote a demo to test `java.util.Random` and I want to produce a repeating list of the same 5 numbers, but I get the same value when set different seeds.In my program, seeds range from 0 to 4. As far as I know, different seeds produce different values and the same seed get the same value. So I think the result will be a repeating list of the same 5 numbers. But the actual values output are all the same. What's wrong with my code? Could anyone tell me?

```
import java.util.Random;

public class Main {
    public Main() {
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        for (int i = 0 ; i <= 255; i++)
        {
            String hex = Integer.toHexString(randInt(0, 255, i % 5));
            System.out.println(hex);
        }
    }
    private static Random rand = new Random();
    public static int randInt(int min, int max, long seed) {
        rand.setSeed(seed);
        System.out.println("seed:" + seed);
        int randomNum = rand.nextInt((max - min) + 1) + min;
        return randomNum;
    }
}
```

The result is :

```
seed:0
bb
seed:1
bb
seed:2
bb
seed:3
bb
seed:4
bb
seed:0
bb
seed:1
bb
seed:2
bb
seed:3
bb
seed:4
bb
seed:0
bb
seed:1
bb
seed:2
bb
seed:3
bb
seed:4
bb
seed:0
bb
seed:1
...
...
...
```

Comment: The more probable answer is that there is a bug in your code. You should isolate the different parts and test whether you do what you think you're doing.

Comment: not sure what you want to achieve, but it is not how you use Random. You set seed once, and then take numbers from it.

Comment: Try just doing `int randomNum = rand.nextInt(max) + min;` It's also worth noting that each time you change the seed it resets, so you will get a repeating list of the same 5 numbers in this case.

Comment: I have printed the seed to console, You can take a look at it, or you can paste the code to IDE and run it.

Comment: No thanks, you can do the debugging yourself.

Comment: (max - min) + 1 equals 256 which gives problems, but if you put 255 it works fine.

Comment: It works even with 257, for some reason you can't use 256.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> As far as I know, different seeds produce different values

This is incorrect, different seeds *may* produce different values, they can also produce the same values.

There are 2^64 possible seeds and `rand.nextInt(256)` can only return 256 different values so many of the seeds must return the same value.

Also the `setSeed` javadoc states

> The implementation of setSeed by class Random happens to use only 48
>   bits of the given seed

So if your seed differs in only the ignored bits all of the values will be the same.

Comment: "different seeds produce different values" is incorrect.  Does the same seed produce the same value on different platforms and devices?

Comment: @dragonfly Yes, unless there is a bug in the platform's `Random` implementation. The javadoc requires the same seed to produce the same values in all Java implementations. Note that some of the methods like `nextFloat` and `nextDouble` have changed over time and may change again in the future, so you might not get the same values if you use different Java versions.

Comment: @dragonfly Also It looks like `Random` does not use `strictfp` so the methods that use floating point numbers may generate slightly different results across platforms.

Answer (score 0):

I have found this implementation on [grepcode](http://grepcode.com/file/repository.grepcode.com/java/root/jdk/openjdk/6-b14/java/util/Random.java#Random.nextInt%28int%29), there's an if statement to detect if n is a power of 2. If n (i.e. the bound) is a power of 2 `(int)((n * (long)next(31)) >> 31);` is used.

```
public int nextInt(int n) {
    if (n <= 0)
         throw new IllegalArgumentException("n must be positive");
    if ((n & -n) == n)  // i.e., n is a power of 2
        return (int)((n * (long)next(31)) >> 31);
    int bits, val;
    do {
        bits = next(31);
        val = bits % n;
    } while (bits - val + (n-1) < 0);
    return val;
}
```

I don't know if this implementation is used in your JDK but this suggests that power of 2 bounds are treated differently.

> The algorithm treats the case where n is a power of two specially: it returns the correct number of high-order bits from the underlying pseudo-random number generator. In the absence of special treatment, the correct number of low-order bits would be returned. Linear congruential pseudo-random number generators such as the one implemented by this class are known to have short periods in the sequence of values of their low-order bits. Thus, this special case greatly increases the length of the sequence of values returned by successive calls to this method if n is a small power of two.